# Corrupt zip file downloaded with Angular from php backend

Tags: angular, http-headers, filesaver.js

I created a method in PHP for downloading a series of pdf files and then archive them in a zip file and sending a `header('Content-type: application/zip')`.

The temporary file is ok. That means that you can unzip the archive with correct files.

The frontend part.
I'm doing a `POST` to backend with:

`downloadSelectedInvoices(data) : Observable<any> {
        let params = { data: JSON.stringify(data) }
        return this.http.post(this.settings.backend.downloadSelectedInvoices, params, this.options)
       .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'));
}`

I'm subscribing to this observable (in the component) and parse the result

`this.downloadZip(result._body);`

```
downloadZip(data){
      let blob = new Blob([data], {
            type: "application/zip"
        });
      FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "invoices.zip");
}
```

It downloads a file but it's corrupt. I can open it and it has just a symbol inside it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have finally managed to make it work.

When you make a `POST` to the backend you need to specify the response via the `ResponseContentType`:

`let options = new RequestOptions({responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob});`